# How to get my hidden div's to show in a drop down menu

Tags: html, css

First please don't make fun of the code it is a work in progress. I am very new to trying to build a website.
I have 4 div's hidden and I have a drop down menu I found online and an currently editing. I am trying to get the drop down menu to call each hidden div but I do not know how to link that. Would someone know how to help me with this. Thanks very much in advance.

```css
/**************************************************************************************************************************************************Search Bar*/
form {
display: flex;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}   
    
.BorderLineSearch {
align-items: center;
border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
margin-bottom: 30px;
padding: 5px 15px;
transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.BorderLineSearch img {
height: 27px;
margin-right: 10px;
}

.BorderLineSearch:hover, .BorderLineSearch:focus {
background-color: transparent;
}

.BorderLineSearch input {
appearance: none;
background-color: transparent;  
border: 0;  
color: #242527; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 300;   
-moz-appearance: none;  
outline: 0; 
-webkit-appearance: none;
width: 800px;   
}

.BorderLineSearch button {
appearance: none;
background-color: transparent;  
border: 0;
color: #aaaaaa!important;   
-moz-appearance: none;  
outline: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

.BorderLineSearch button:hover {
appearance: none;
background-color: transparent;  
border: 0;
color: #aaaaaa!important;   
-moz-appearance: none;  
outline: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

.BorderLineSearch button:focus {
appearance: none;
background-color: transparent;  
border: 0;
color: #aaaaaa!important;   
-moz-appearance: none;  
outline: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

/************************************************************************************************************************************************Place Holder*/
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
color: #aaaaaa;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
color: #aaaaaa;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
opacity: 1;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
color: #aaaaaa;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
}


.collapse{
background: #cdf;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  
}
.collapse + input{
  display: none; /* hide the checkboxes */
}
.collapse + input + div{
  display:none;
}
.collapse + input:checked + div{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo"><label class="collapse" for="_1">Collapse 1</label></option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>


<label class="collapse" for="_1">Collapse 1</label>
<input id="_1" type="radio" name="c1"> 
<div><div class="BorderLineSearch">
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search?q=">
<img src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/search-icons/g-favicon.ico">
<input type="text" name="q" class="searchTerm" placeholder=" Search the Web..." autocomplete="off"/>
<button id="button"><font size="4"><i class="fa fa-search" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></font></button>
</form>
</div>
</div>

<label class="collapse" for="_2">Collapse 2</label>
<input id="_2" type="radio" name="c1">
<div><div class="BorderLineSearch">
<form method="get" action="http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=">
<img src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/search-icons/yayoo.png">
<input type="text" name="q" class="searchTerm" placeholder=" Search the Web..." autocomplete="off"/>
<button id="button"><font size="4"><i class="fa fa-search" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></font></button>
</form>
</div></div>

<label class="collapse" for="_3">Collapse 2</label>
<input id="_3" type="radio" name="c1">
<div><div class="BorderLineSearch">
<form method="get" action="http://duckduckgo.com/?q=">
<img src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/search-icons/duck.png">
<input type="text" name="q" class="searchTerm" placeholder=" Search the Web..." autocomplete="off"/>
<button id="button"><font size="4"><i class="fa fa-search" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></font></button>
</form>
</div></div>

<label class="collapse" for="_4">Collapse 2</label>
<input id="_4" type="radio" name="c1">
<div><div class="BorderLineSearch">
<form method="get" action="http://www.bing.com/search?q=">
<img src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/search-icons/bing.png">
<input type="text" name="q" class="searchTerm" placeholder=" Search the Web..." autocomplete="off"/>
<button id="button"><font size="4"><i class="fa fa-search" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></font></button>
</form>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javaScript and JQUERY here is a working [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jvndt2ph/)

HTML file

```
<select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo"><label class="collapse" for="_1">Collapse 1</label></option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
<div id="saab" class="cars" style="display:none">Data for saab </div>
<div id="opel" class="cars" style="display:none"> Data for opel</div>
<div id="audi" class="cars" style="display:none"> Data for audi </div>
<div id="volvo" class="cars" style="display:none"> Data for volvo </div>
```

Jquery

```
 $(function() {
        $('#cars').change(function(){
            $('.cars').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
```